# Facebook custom style: visibility hidden works, display none doesn't

Tags: css, facebook

I'm trying to write a custom style sheet to rename Facebook Groups in the left sidebar. I am not an admin of the groups and cannot change the names, I just want to read something there that is meaningful to me, especially when many group names begin with the same words and appear the same in the sidebar list.

What I try to do is hide the original name and insert my custom name.

I can insert my custom group name with something like:

```
#navItem_group_136453550474635 a div:nth-child(2):after{
content: "Custom name";
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot "shrink" the div with the original name with "display:none", only hide it, so that in effect there is some empty space pushing my custom name to a second line.

This works:

```
#navItem_group_162405550444366 a div div{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

This does not work:

```
#navItem_group_162405550444366 a div div{
display: none;
}
```

"display:none" does not work, presumably because the div already has `display:block`, but why doen't my browser style sheet overwrite that?

I'm using safari under OS 10.8.?, but I believe this shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "display:none" does not work, presumably because the div already has display:block, but why doen't my browser style sheet overwrite that?

Does your rule have the same specifity as the one Facebook is using to format this element?

Have you tried adding `!important` to your declaration, to overwrite the formatting of Facebook’s own stylesheet?

Comment: Thank you. `! important` works. What do you mean with "specifity"?